# How to use methods defined in a python scipt from a console like ipython

Tags: python, scripting, import, ipython

I have written a python script with methods in it. Now I want to use methods from that script in ipython. How do I import it for use in ipython?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file with your functions in it is called mod.py, just:

```
>>> import mod
>>> mod.myfunction()
```

Comment: This requires that the module is locatable, it has to be either in the current directory or in PYTHONPATH.  Hence the 'cd' in my answer.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are several options and all of them work with specific advantages and disadvantages:

```
from module import *
import module
%edit module.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside IPython:

```
cd folder/containing/module
import module
module.function(1, 2, 3)
```